# What programming languages are used to build tor hidden webpages (dark web webpages)

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

**Which programming languages are used to write onion webpages . and is it possible to use tor browser on Linux distributions with obtaining full anonymity? , and finally where can I study the onion networking properly is there any source?
**

Answer (score 2):

Great Questions! It's awesome that you're curious about protecting your identity and what you do on the web! After all, it should be nobody elses business but your own. Congratulations!

I take issue with the answer provided by one user that said *"Any programming language that you would use for normal websites (HTML/JavaScript/CSS for frontend/static content, NodeJS/PHP/Ruby/Python/Java/etc for the backend server)"*

The purpose of the TOR Network and .onion routing is anonymity. Some of the worst security hacks against the end user are done through JavaScript. NodeJS is JavaScript.

There's a couple different layers of the dark web. There's a surface darkweb. This is where most people get into trouble. This is where malicious sites live. If a site on the dark web requires or allows JavaScript then you are not anonymous. A little bit further down you'll find where truly secure .onion sites are.

You asked, *"is it possible to use tor browser on Linux distributions with obtaining full anonymity?*

The answer is yes. In fact there's a linux distro specifically to do as you suggest. It's a very hardened version of Debian written specifically for the TOR network and your anonymity. It's called "Tails." Learn about it. Also learn about "Whonix." That's another super secure method to access it.

Be safe, protect your identity especially if you're a whistle blower or reporting things others don't want reported. DON'T FALL IN! Peace.

Answer (score 0):

> Which programming languages are used to write onion webpages

Any programming language that you would use for normal websites (HTML/JavaScript/CSS for frontend/static content, NodeJS/PHP/Ruby/Python/Java/etc for the backend server).

> and is it possible to use tor browser on Linux distributions with obtaining full anonymity?

You can use Tor Browser on Linux, but there is no such thing as full anonymity.

> where can I study the onion networking properly is there any source?

The [original Tor paper](https://svn-archive.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.pdf) still gives a good introduction to how the network works. One part of the network design that you may want to search online for is "onion routing".

Comment: thanks for the answers . i meant by anonymity is that does it hide your ip address only or it hides content accessed by you?

Comment: @Steven-falser It only hides your IP address. The server still knows what content is accessed, it just does know *who* accessed it.

Comment: what is the difference between tor and proxies /proxychains and which is better

Comment: JavaScript should not be used, in fact "JavaScript is required to be disabled in the Tor browser for many security reasons". So this answer is not adequate. Any frontend language can not be used, as several of them depend on Javascript.

Comment: @CodeOrElse JavaScript is enabled by default in Tor Browser, and I'd guess that most people leave JavaScript enabled.